# Getting media player state in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have amended my code in **App.xaml.cs**

But i have an error at **"this.ApplicationLifetimeObjects.Add(new XNAAsyncDispatcher(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)));"** (Placed at end of my App.xaml.cs)

The error is

- "System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(double) is a method but is used like a type"
- System.Windows.Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects is a property but is used like a type
- Identifier expected
- Invalid token '(' in a class, struct or interface member declaration
- Method must have a return type

Below is the whole piece of my App.xaml.cs

```
namespace Alarm_Clock

{

public class GlobalData

{
    public BitmapImage bitmapImage;
} 

public partial class App : Application
{
    public static GlobalData globalData;

    public class XNAAsyncDispatcher : IApplicationService
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _frameworkDispatcherTimer;

    public XNAAsyncDispatcher(TimeSpan dispatchInterval)
    {
        _frameworkDispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _frameworkDispatcherTimer.Tick += frameworkDispatcherTimer_Tick;
        _frameworkDispatcherTimer.Interval = dispatchInterval;
    }
    void IApplicationService.StartService(ApplicationServiceContext context) { _frameworkDispatcherTimer.Start(); }
    void IApplicationService.StopService() { _frameworkDispatcherTimer.Stop(); }
    void frameworkDispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); }
}

    public static string imagePath
    {
        //get { return "PhotoNote_{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.jpg"; }
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides easy access to the root frame of the Phone Application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The root frame of the Phone Application.</returns>
    public PhoneApplicationFrame RootFrame { get; private set; }

    //Global variables for the WriteableBitmap objects used throughout the application.
    public static WriteableBitmap CapturedImage;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for the Application object.
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        globalData = new GlobalData();
        globalData.bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(); 

        // Global handler for uncaught exceptions. 
        UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

        // Show graphics profiling information while debugging.
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // Display the current frame rate counters.
            Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;

            // Show the areas of the app that are being redrawn in each frame.
            //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableRedrawRegions = true;

            // Enable non-production analysis visualization mode, 
            // which shows areas of a page that are being GPU accelerated with a colored overlay.
            //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableCacheVisualization = true;
        }

        // Standard Silverlight initialization
        InitializeComponent();

        // Phone-specific initialization
        InitializePhoneApplication();
    }

    // Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
    // This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    // Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
    // This code will not execute when the application is first launched
    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    // Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background)
    // This code will not execute when the application is closing
    private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    // Code to execute when the application is closing (eg, user hit Back)
    // This code will not execute when the application is deactivated
    private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    // Code to execute if a navigation fails
    private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }

    // Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }

    #region Phone application initialization

    // Avoid double-initialization
    private bool phoneApplicationInitialized = false;

    // Do not add any additional code to this method
    private void InitializePhoneApplication()
    {
        if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
            return;

        // Create the frame but don't set it as RootVisual yet; this allows the splash
        // screen to remain active until the application is ready to render.
        RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
        RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

        // Handle navigation failures
        RootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;

        // Ensure we don't initialize again
        phoneApplicationInitialized = true;
    }

    // Do not add any additional code to this method
    private void CompleteInitializePhoneApplication(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the root visual to allow the application to render
        if (RootVisual != RootFrame)
            RootVisual = RootFrame;

        // Remove this handler since it is no longer needed
        RootFrame.Navigated -= CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
    }

    #endregion
    this.ApplicationLifetimeObjects.Add(new XNAAsyncDispatcher(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)));
}
```

}

The pause just dont work in my code below.

This is my whole piece of code:

```
namespace Alarm_Clock
{

    public partial class AlarmRing : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        int songSelectedIndex;

        public AlarmRing()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait;
            //Get the DateTime.Now and place it into "timeTxtBlock" text block
            timeTxtBlock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();


            //Read from Isolated storage queSetting.txt for the number of question to answer by the user
            //Read from Isolated storage music.txt for the selected music to play when the alarm ring
            var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

                IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                try
                {
                    StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SettingFolder\\music.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore));

                    songSelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt16(readFile.ReadLine());
                    readFile.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //If the user did not select the music to be played when the alarm ring it will play the first music by default
                    songSelectedIndex = 0;
                }


            using (var ml = new MediaLibrary())
            {
                //Play the music using media player from the song collection
                FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
                MediaPlayer.MediaStateChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(MediaPlayer_MediaStateChanged);
                MediaPlayer.Play(ml.Songs[songSelectedIndex]);
                MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
                MediaPlayer.IsMuted = false;
                MediaPlayer.IsShuffled = false;
                MediaPlayer.IsVisualizationEnabled = false;

            }

            //Load code
            loadtime();
        }

        static void MediaPlayer_MediaStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Paused)
            {
                MediaPlayer.Resume();
            }

        }

        void loadtime()
        {
            ringingAlarm.Begin();

            //Get the DateTime.Now
            String timeNow = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();


            using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                foreach (string labels in storage.GetFileNames("*"))
                {
                    XElement _xml;
                    IsolatedStorageFileStream location = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(labels, System.IO.FileMode.Open, storage);
                    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(location);
                    _xml = XElement.Parse(file.ReadToEnd());
                    if (_xml.Name.LocalName != null)
                    {
                        XAttribute time = _xml.Attribute("time");
                        //Get the day of the week
                        String dayOfWeek = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString("F");

                        if (timeNow == time.Value.ToString())
                        {
                            //"textBlock2" text block will display the label of the alarm
                            textBlock2.Text = labels;
                        }
                    }
                    file.Dispose();
                    location.Dispose();
                }

            }

        }

        string settingQues;
        string settingQuesPassToGame;
        string format;
        string format1;
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            //Try get the value of number of question to be answered by the user that is pass over from setClockPage.xaml
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("settingQues", out settingQues))
                settingQuesPassToGame = settingQues;

            //Try get the format that is passed over
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("format", out format))
                format1 = format;
        }

        //Display a pop up message box with instruction
        //And navigate to "Start.xaml"
        private void gameBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("To dismiss alarm" + System.Environment.NewLine + "- Answer selected IQ question" + System.Environment.NewLine + "- With all correct answer");
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Start.xaml?ringingAlarmTitle=" + textBlock2.Text + "&ringingAlarmTime=" + timeTxtBlock.Text + "&format1=" + format1, UriKind.Relative));
        }

        protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

        public Visibility visible { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I place `MediaPlayer.MediaStateChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(MediaPlayer_MediaStateChanged);` at the constructor there is an error.

The error is `MediaPlayer.MediaStateChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(MediaPlayer_MediaStateChanged) is a method but is use like a type`.

---

I have changed my code but it still dosent work

```
static void MediaPlayer_MediaStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 if (MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Paused) 
 {
     MediaPlayer.Resume();
 }

}
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should close that `StreamReader` when you're done reading what you want out of the file.

Comment: Your App.xaml.cs is obviously wrong.  You can't place a method call just inside a class declaration.  It has to be inside some method/property definition.  The other issue is likely due to a naming conflict.  Don't name an instance of a `MediaPlayer` Control "MediaPlayer" - things get confused as to whether you're referencing the instance of the type name.  Change the control name to "mediaPlayer" (no cap) or something else and it's going to be easier to decipher the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to dispatch XNA Events manual in Windows Phone 7 Apps:

```
public class XNAAsyncDispatcher : IApplicationService
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _frameworkDispatcherTimer;

    public XNAAsyncDispatcher(TimeSpan dispatchInterval)
    {
        _frameworkDispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _frameworkDispatcherTimer.Tick += frameworkDispatcherTimer_Tick;
        _frameworkDispatcherTimer.Interval = dispatchInterval;
    }

    void IApplicationService.StartService(ApplicationServiceContext context) { _frameworkDispatcherTimer.Start(); }
    void IApplicationService.StopService() { _frameworkDispatcherTimer.Stop(); }
    void frameworkDispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); }
}
```

Add this to the end of your `public App()`

```
public App()
{
    // Other stuff

    // End
    this.ApplicationLifetimeObjects.Add(new XNAAsyncDispatcher(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)));
}
```

Complete Guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff842408.aspx

Comment: Where should i add the dispatcher code?? In my current code page?? Or create a new class?

Comment: @ben In your existing App.xaml.cs

Comment: this one "public class XNAAsyncDispatcher : IApplicationService" at App.xaml.cs too??

Comment: @ben yeah sure you can do that

Comment: @ben updated. Add ApplicationLifetimeObjects to the end of App() ... not the end of the file