# Windows Phone 7 : Silverlight and playing Music

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, xna-4.0

I have built a simple game in WP7 and I am trying to add background music to it using MediaPlayer.  The problem is it just bombs with

{"An unexpected error has occurred."}   System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

Code

```
try
                {
                    MediaPlayer.Stop();
                    // Timer to run the XNA internals (MediaPlayer is from XNA)
                    DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
                    dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33);
                    dt.Tick += delegate { try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); } catch { } };
                    dt.Start();

                    Uri pathToFile = new Uri("Audio/music.m4a", UriKind.Relative);
                    Song playingSong = Song.FromUri("Music", pathToFile);
                    MediaPlayer.Play(playingSong);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    musicFailed = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show("Warning, music failed to play however you can still continue to play your game.");
                }
            }
```

I tried a few tweaks, converting file to mp3, different paths etc.  **The file is marked for copy always and content type**  I also tried removing the Dispatcher as dont know what that is for.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think Silverlight requires .wma files. EDIT: At least in Silverlight 4, I can't speak for SL 5 with XNA.

Comment: Is this happen when debugger is connected? Try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180729%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Comment: Yes when the debugger is connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can convert your audio files to WAV format, you can try using the XNA SoundEffect and SoundEffectInstance classes:

```
SoundEffect se = SoundEffect.FromStream(isolatedStorageFileStream);
SoundEffectInstance sei = se.CreateInstance();
sei.Play();
```

For this to work, you will need to reference the XNA library (Microsoft.XNA.Framework) and initialize the framework in this way:

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application>
    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <local:XNAFrameworkDispatcherService />
        ...
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>    
</Application>
```

And create this class somewhere in the app namespace ("local" in the previous xaml references this namespace):

```
public class XNAFrameworkDispatcherService : IApplicationService
{
    private DispatcherTimer frameworkDispatcherTimer;
    public XNAFrameworkDispatcherService()
    {
        this.frameworkDispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        this.frameworkDispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333);
        this.frameworkDispatcherTimer.Tick += frameworkDispatcherTimer_Tick;
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    }
    void frameworkDispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); }
    void IApplicationService.StartService(ApplicationServiceContext context) { this.frameworkDispatcherTimer.Start(); }
    void IApplicationService.StopService() { this.frameworkDispatcherTimer.Stop(); }
}
```

Comment: Wont this interfere with other sound files?

Comment: All sounds played in this way are independent with each other. Meaning you can have one, two or ten sounds being played at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your timer maybe not fired the first tick and `FrameworkDispatcher.Update()` not ran. Then `Play` throws a `System.InvalidOperationException`.

Better dispatch XNA Events global in your Application.

Complete Guide: [XNAAsyncDispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034507/getting-media-player-state-in-windows-phone-7/7046786#7046786)